# Run Webpack script in Task Runner before publish project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, webpack

Here are standard bindings in Task Runner in Visual Studio 2019 (Before build, After build, Clean, Project open).

I configured scripts for Webpack in `package.json` file (dev, prod etc.). Everything works well during development.

What i need is to execute my configured Webpack script to produce minified js/css files before pubish and then publish my ASP.NET Core project (with minified versions of that files).

I can not figure out how to connect Task Runner with publish profile (*.pubxml) and Webpack script.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for my problem. I added new `Target` in my `Properties -> PublishProfiles -> _name_.pubxml` file:

```
...
  <Target Name="PrePublish" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="webpack --mode production"/>
  </Target>
...
```

This Webpack command executes **before** build and **before** publish, so brand new minified files are picked up and published.